# Scrolling not working in android xml layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I am getting problem to make this layout scroll it is not scrolling. I have also used the Scrollview in this. I am not able to detect why it is not working. This is a login screen with Social Login buttons at the bottom of the screen. but it is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mail_login"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/login_bg_img"
android:isScrollContainer="true">


   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Login_signinText" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

                    android:src="@mipmap/login_logo_icon" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@mipmap/login_input_bar1"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_email_login"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:hint="Username"

                            android:maxLength="20"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="#777e86"
                            android:textColorHint="#777e86"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/Login_username" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_singup_password"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@mipmap/login_input_bar2"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"

                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_password_login"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:hint="Password"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"

                            android:maxLength="15"
                            android:maxLines="1"


                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="#777e86"
                            android:textColorHint="#777e86"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/Login_username" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_forget_password"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Forgot Password?"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/Login_forgotpassword" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_sign_up"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Forget Password"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/Login_forgotpassword" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <RelativeLayout

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/login_btn"
                        style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/login_btn" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="Let me in"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <!--<LinearLayout-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:orientation="vertical"-->
                <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="15dp"-->
                <!--android:paddingBottom="10dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">-->

                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/forgot_login"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:paddingBottom="8dp"-->
                <!--android:paddingRight="5dp"-->
                <!--android:text="Forgot Password ?"-->
                <!--android:textSize="18sp"-->
                <!--android:textColor="#fff"/>-->
                <!--</LinearLayout>-->

                <!--<LinearLayout-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:orientation="vertical"-->
                <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="25dp"-->
                <!--android:paddingBottom="10dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">-->

                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/Sign_up"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:paddingBottom="8dp"-->
                <!--android:paddingRight="5dp"-->
                <!--android:text="Don't have an account? Sign Up"-->
                <!--android:textSize="18sp"-->
                <!--android:textColor="#fff"/>-->
                <!--</LinearLayout>-->

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_fb"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@mipmap/login_facebook_btn"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_google"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@mipmap/login_google_btn"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_twitter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@mipmap/login_twitter_btn"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Since your scrollview's height is wrap_content... please change it to fill_parent/match_parent

Answer (score 0):

Try to work like that

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/llbottom"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >
```

and take id to your bottom id

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/llbottom"
    android:weightSum="3">
```

Comment: remove the android:isScrollContainer="true"... in main Container Top Relavtive layout

Comment: Why you take android:isScrollContainer="true" in each... remove it... and try

Answer (score 0):

close the  tag at the end.`</RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this attribute to your scrollviewer:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

> You use this.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mail_login"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="12sp" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_email_login"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:hint="Username"

                            android:maxLength="20"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="#777e86"
                            android:textColorHint="#777e86"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_singup_password"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"

                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_password_login"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:hint="Password"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"

                            android:maxLength="15"
                            android:maxLines="1"


                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="#777e86"
                            android:textColorHint="#777e86"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_forget_password"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Forgot Password?"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_sign_up"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Forget Password"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <RelativeLayout

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/login_btn"
                        style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="Let me in"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>



            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_fb"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You use this it's working perfectly in my device. you copy total code in xml and check whether it's working or not.only Uoy need to change mipmap file. @samo

Comment: But this is not the way..why are you fixing the height?That may vary from device to device

Comment: While it may still work. Its always nice to explain what changes you made and how that affects the output, in your answer.

Comment: @kgandroid if you don't want then you can use as wrap or match.here i fixed the size because of testing purpose.